# How to debug a shared library (.so) in VS2019 (NDK Projekt)

Tags: visual-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries, breakpoints, debug-symbols

I have a **NDK Project** in **Visual Studio 2019** which uses several shared libraries.

In the project which contains the android_main function i can set breakpoints and use them without problems. If I set a breakpoint in one of my **shared libraries (.so)** and start the debugger I get this message:

> **The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained.**

How can I load the missing symbols?

I'm using the platform toolset Clang 5.0

---

What I tried so far:

With this command I proved that symbols are present:

```
llvm-nm -D libMySharedLib.so
```

### In the modules window (in debug mode) I can see that symbols are loaded for my .so module.

What I'm guessing is wrong:

With NDK typically such problems show up when the debugging info is being stripped away. There is also an option to disable this behavior which is called "donotstrip" in Android Studio. But I'm on Visual Studio.

Comment: Perhaps you can check this docs: [Load symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-modules-window?view=vs-2019#load-symbols), and [Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Ok. Now with the modules window I can see that symbols are loaded for my .so library. But the breakpoint is still not hit.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, in Visual Studio, when starting the debugger, **the respective shared library (.so) project must be set as "Startup Project"**. Only the breakpoints of the current Startup Project are reached or those breakpoints that are contained in .cpp files, which in turn are part of the respective Startup Project. This is of course not very comfortable and if someone here knows a better solution, a corresponding comment would be very helpful.

Anyway, if a shared library project is to be launched, the appropriate path and name of the .apk file must be set under "Configuration Properties"->"Debugging"->"Package to Launch".